# Apigee pass Authorization header

Tags: apigee

We have Apigee passing calls directly to our backend services.
However Apigee seems to remove the headers for Authorization: Bearer

How can I force Apigee to keep Authorization headers and not strip them out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check in your service, in **Remove Header Authorization** (it is policy that auto created by apigee) you will see the code below:

```
 <Remove>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="Authorization"/>
            <Header name="Accept"/>
            <Header name="accept-encoding"/>
            <Header name="cache-control"/>
            <Header name="cookie"/>
            <Header name="Postman-Token"/>
        </Headers>
 </Remove>
```

So, you have to remove `<Header name="Authorization"/>`

Comment: Where can I check for this policy in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes Pim, that is correct, just to be more precise while generating a proxy, Apigee will add below Policy code by default-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="remove-header-authorization">
    <DisplayName>Remove Header Authorization</DisplayName>
    <Remove>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="Authorization"/>
        </Headers>
    </Remove>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <AssignTo createNew="false" transport="http" type="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

Comment: Where can I check for this policy in the UI?

Comment: hit 1 request in bebug mode and check the policy from left to right, there you will find this policy. It will most probably be in pre request flow.